# C program to read 2 numbers, make range from it and verify if it's positive?

Tags: c

It there anyway that i can make my user input 2 numbers, make a range from it and verify if the input are positive?

e.g: User inputs 1 and 10
Program should verify if 1 and 10 is positive and make 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 10 so i can check which are prime and non prime numbers and how many of them are prime and non prime.

I've tried made from this:

```
 // Request number of numbers for range
 printf ("Enter the number of integers and positives you want to add \ n");
 scanf ("% d", & n);

 // Quit the numbers and check if they are positive
 printf ("Enter% d integers and positive numbers \ n, n);
 for (c = 1; c <= n; c ++) {
 do{
 printf ("Please enter a positive number");
 scanf ("% d", & value);
 }
 while (value <0);

 scanf ("% d",% value);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, why not? Use a loop to go over the intermediate numbers.

Comment: What kinda loop? And How?

Comment: depends...any loop would do, it's upto your design.

Comment: `int j; for (j = smallest_input; j <= largest_input; ++j) { /* do stuff with j */};`

Comment: I warmly recommend to get/read a book about C programming. Your question is really very basic. You want to determine prime numbers and even struggle to read in two values, check them, and to loop over the range they span?

Comment: The prime numbers it's just an example, i kinda know this is very basic, i'm a beginner on programming, i've also read some examples from other websites but i get confused that's why i asked here, do you have any free c programming book that can help me @Scheff ? That would help a lot thanks

Comment: I made this at beginer @4386427:

     // Request number of numbers for range
     printf ("Enter the number of integers and positives you want to add \ n");
     scanf ("% d", & n);
     
     // Quit the numbers and check if they are positive
     printf ("Enter% d integers and positive numbers \ n, n);
     for (c = 1; c <= n; c ++) {
     of{
     printf ("Please enter a positive number");
     scanf ("% d", & value);
     }
     while (value <0);
     
     scanf ("% d",% value);
     }

Comment: @FranciscoP. Don't post your code in a comment. Edit your question and post the code there.

Comment: I hardly can recommend a good book for C. The one, I used is decades old and the publisher probably even does not exist anymore. I tried to find a book list here but it seems to be deleted. (I once read a discussion that book recommendations are opinion-based and hence not matching the requirements of this community.) You may google yourself. I found this by google: [30 Awesome C Programming Books recommended by Stackoverflow](http://bestprogrammingbooks.com/30-c-books-recommended-by-stackoverflow/). Some of the titles seem to be available online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've made more research and made the final program:

**PS:** As i said the Prime were just to give an example and used some code from @Guillaume MILAN Answer

```
int main(){

        int num1,num2,i,x,y;  
        int Pair = 0, Impair = 0;

        printf("Insirt a Number:\n");
        scanf("%d",&num1);

        printf("Insert a Numer:\n");
        scanf("%d",&num2);

            if (num1 > num2) {
                x = num2; y = num1;
            } else { 
                x = num1; y = num2;
            }

            if (x <0 || y <0) {
                printf("%d Insert Positive Number\n");
                return -1;  //Gives an error
            }   

        for( i = x; i <= y; i++ ) {        
            if ( i%2 == 0){
            printf("%d Pair\n",i);
            Pair ++;
            } else {
            printf("%d Impair\n",i);
            Impair ++;
            }
        }

        printf(" Nº of Pair: %d\n Nº of Impairs: %d", Pair, Impair);
        return 0;
 }
```

Thanks everyone who helped me.

Comment: You should validate your answer to close it. 
BTW main should return a `int` so you need to replace `return;` by `return 0;`

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeMILAN for everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
int is_prime(int n);
int verify(int a, int b) {
    int x,y; // placed as 0 < x < y
    if (a>b) {
        x = b; y = a;
    } else { 
        x = a; y = b;
    }
    if (x<0 || y<0) {
        return -1; //error 
    }

    for (int i=x; i <=y; i++) {
        is_prime(i);
    }
    return 0;
}

int is_prime(int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
        if ((n/i)*n == n) {
            printf("%d divide %d", i, n);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d is prime",n);
    return 1;
}
```

If you want to place it in table you will need to `malloc` it. But it will be more line of code and you will need to return a `int*` (pointer on `int`)

Comment: Your algorithm seems to implement even/odd testing not testing for prime numbers...

Comment: LOL sorry, english is not my native language and prime looks like to even in my native language... 
Will correct it ^^ sorry.

Comment: `if (x<0 && y<0)` is wrong. Should be `if (x<0 || y<0)` or simply `if (x<0)` as x and y is already sorted.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<n/2; i++) { if ((n/i)*n == n) {` Division by zero isn't a good thing.

Comment: Should be     (i=0;i<n; i++) then     if(i%2 == 0) { ?? @4386427

Comment: @FranciscoP. I modified the code to get the prime number. `i%2 == 0` was for even and odd test when I was miss understanding.